# Is the '0V' on a non-isolated buck converter the same on the input as it is on the output?

Tags: ground, buck, pir

I'm working on a project where I want to switch a load (utility LED light, +- 20W) using a motion sensor. The PIR can only operate at a maximum of 12 volts, while the load can be operated at a voltage between 12-36 volts. I want to power this circuit using a lead acid battery, with the light on the 'unregulated' output and the PIR regulated (with a buck converter) to something like 5V. The PIR also outputs a 3,3 volt signal, so I made a circuit to boost this to the battery voltage. I was wondering if a circuit like this would work or if the '0V' line would be different between the battery negative and the buck converter negative output.

[image: The signal boost circuit, the 3,3V supply simulates the PIR output]
Signal boost circuit
[image: The whole circuit, with gate driver and pulldown being the circuit in]
Whole circuit simplified

Comment: Yes. Same ground. Consider ditching the BJT inverter-pull-up-scheme if 3.3 V is enough to drive your FET.

Comment: It strongly depends on the exact converter. For most of them this is true, but no one can tell you without knowing its schematic. Some DC/DC converters which can output constant current have current sense resistor in the negative path, but it would not be a problem if you power the PIR sensor only.

Comment: Aha, so a buck converter without current control will probably be fine. Thank you! Unfortunately the mosfet needs about 10V, it's an IRF540 mosfet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments the ground is probably the same if some constraints are satisfied:

- Non-isolated buck converter
- Buck converter without current regulation, current regulated converters have a shunt at the ground line changing the voltage
- Buck-boost converters have a negative (afaik)  'ground' voltage and thus are not usable